How do I sum up several Christoffel symbols?
I tried to do the proof that the Levi Civita connection is unique and torsion free from my book and I already did it once in the past, but I havent worked for a time with relativity and now I sort of do not see it :(
My book says:
\begin{aligned}
0=\nabla_{a} g_{b c}=\partial_{a} g_{b c}-\Gamma_{b a}^{k} g_{k c}-\Gamma_{c a}^{l} g_{b l} (1.13)
\end{aligned}
Likewise, we get from cyclic permutations of the indices

\begin{aligned}
\nabla_{c} g_{a b} & =\partial_{c} g_{a b}-\Gamma_{a c}^{k} g_{k b}-\Gamma_{b c}^{l} g_{a l} (1.14) \\
\nabla_{b} g_{c a} & =\partial_{b} g_{c a}-\Gamma_{c b}^{k} g_{k a}-\Gamma_{a b}^{l} g_{c l} (1.15)
\end{aligned}
If we now subtract equations ( (1.1 .4) ) and ( (1.1 .5) ) from equation ( (1.1 .3) ) and use the fact that $\nabla$ is torsion free (meaning that $\Gamma$ is symmetric in its lower indices), we get
\begin{aligned}
0=\partial_{a} g_{b c}-\partial_{c} g_{a b}-\partial_{b} g_{c a}+2 \Gamma_{b c}^{k} g_{a k}
\end{aligned}
Now my question is where the 2 Christoffels come from? How do I sum up several Christoffel symbols with different indices?

what do you mean by ‘how do I sum up several Christoffel symbols with different indices’? Just subtract the two equations from the first (and keep in mind dummy indices can always be relabelled), what’s the issue you’re facing?

@peek-a-boo when I subtract these equations, I think I would end up with the 3 partial gs and 6 different Christoffels, because none of them has the same indices. But this is obviously not the case and I suppose the answer lays within the relabelling of dummy indices - which of these Christoffels are actually the same or what are these dummy indices and to what can I relabel them?

You have six $\Gamma g$ terms, but four of them cancel, and the other two give you the $2\Gamma g$ term in your last equation. For example, take the first $\Gamma g$ in (1.13) and the last one from (1.15). Subtracting gives
\begin{align}
-\Gamma^k_{ba}g_{kc}-(-\Gamma^l_{ab}g_{cl})&=-\Gamma^k_{ba}g_{kc}+\Gamma^l_{ab}g_{cl}\\
&=-\Gamma^k_{ab}g_{kc}+\Gamma^l_{ab}g_{cl}\tag{torsion-freeness}\\
&=-\Gamma^k_{ab}g_{kc}+\Gamma^l_{ab}g_{lc}\tag{$g$ is symmetric}\\
&=-\Gamma^k_{ab}g_{kc}+\Gamma^k_{ab}g_{kc}\tag{relabel $l\to k$}\\
&=0.
\end{align}
And just to be clear on why we can relabel the index $l$ to $k$ on the second term, the meaning of $\Gamma^l_{ab}g_{lc}$ is a summation:
\begin{align}
\Gamma^l_{ab}g_{lc}&:=\sum_{l=1}^n\Gamma^l_{ab}g_{lc}
=\sum_{i=1}^n\Gamma^i_{ab}g_{ic}
=\sum_{@=1}^n\Gamma^@_{ab}g_{@c}
=\sum_{\star=1}^n\Gamma^{\star}_{ab}g_{\star c}
=\sum_{\sharp=1}^n\Gamma^{\sharp}_{ab}g_{\sharp c}=\Gamma^k_{ab}g_{kc}.
\end{align}
The choice of dummy index does not matter; all these are the same quantity, equal to
\begin{align}
\Gamma^1_{ab}g_{1c}+ \Gamma^2_{ab}g_{2c}+\dots + \Gamma^n_{ab}g_{nc}.
\end{align}
I explained what happens to two out of the six $\Gamma g$ terms. I’ll let you figure out why two others cancel, and why the last two remain and give the final $+2\Gamma g$ term in your last equation.

This helps me a lot, thank you! I somehow forgot about writing it up as sum and then it becomes crystal-clear, why one can relabel indices :) I suppose we are left with 2 Christoffels because the full calculation has two minus and four plus? Like the sign changes when subtracting the whole term and we end up with 2 out of 4 vanishing christoffels, and 2 that are left? :)
Thank you so much!
